# Weird text highlighting problem on website

Tags: web, highlighting

I have this strange problem on my web page where if you click below the left side-panel, all the links get highlighted.  It happens in firefox, not IE.  I don't know why its only the side-panel that it happens to.  Its not really a big deal but its extremely annoying to me, is there any way to stop it?  If you want to check it out, the site is http://www.bhslaughter.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found out what it was.  I had the left side menu floated inside the table.  It was a left over from before I used the table to layout the page

Answer (score 0):

Not to sound harsh, but that's a serious case of div-itis. You might want to check the number of links that you have, the open and closing of the div's, empty anchor links and the wrapping of your multiple tables.

Good luck with your project.

Comment: Well the site validates as XHTML 1.1, so I know all the tags are closed properly.  I cleaned out a few leftover divs that weren't needed.  Not sure what you mean about empty links or wrapping multiple tables though

Comment: Here is one in particular that is sitting outside of one of your container div's. "<a id='community' class='MMBTS' href='forums/' >&nbsp;</a>".  I don't know if this would have anything to do with the weird highlighting, but I can see that it's not surounded by a div with the class of "clix".

On the table issue. I counted 20+ tables being used. Most are found in the center column for content, but I did notice that the main menu, and the content are surrond by a table along with the footer. Might want to take a look at those to see if there might be an issue there. Good luck!

Comment: There was a div around that link but I removed it since it was useless.  I found out something else, it only occurs on pages where the center column content is longer then the menu.  And on other pages, like the gallery, there's only 3 tables.  I don't think nested tables would be the cause of the problem though